How can I find a Solana transaction based on date/ time, without knowing the wallet, signature, etc.?
I'm looking to ID a particular buy on Solana, based on a date/ time from 8 days ago. I know the amount and approx time. I'm hoping to find the coin this person bought. I'm able to figure out a block to start looking in. (But no wallet, signature, or coin to search.)
I have limited experience in Python, from teaching myself web-scraping. I've only begun learning API calls. I know about Solscan and Solana Explorer, and have been looking at transactions, but can't easily ID transaction amounts, or understand the difference between 'votes,' 'swaps,' 'create,' 'liquidate,' 'SwapBaseIn' on Solscan -- or 'Compute Budget Program,' 'Token Program' on Solana Explorer.
I know I'm looking for a needle in a haystack, but hoping to just get some bearings. Is this doable? Is there a process you'd recommend (that doesn't require me to start learning Javascript while I'm already trying to learn Python?) Can any of it be done with my web-scraping knowledge?
Thanks!
So far, I've used Solana Explorer to ID the block, inside 10 minutes of the assumed transaction time. (I'm trying to find a transaction based on a X.com post showing the transaction amount, and using the time of the post.)
Then, I'm looking at the transactions inside that block, and trying to understand which are buys, and which are other Solana housekeeping, etc. -But each transaction requires the step of clicking into those transactions, and making sense of what's happened. I'm lost.

Hello user25669056, Thank you for asking this question, as I asked the same question and didnt receive any help from anyone...so thank you. Also,I would like to say, THANK YOU to chalda for answering this question, in such great detail...it really helped me, a lot!!!  So...Thank you❗️❗️❗️

I believe this is difficult.
At the start, I can think of an issue that despite you knowing the timeframe and amount you don't know if the token was a standard Solana SPL Token (https://spl.solana.com/token) - but this is most probable (99%). Second, you don't know if it was a token transferred to the owner's wallet or it was bought through some web3 platform (https://mango.markets/, https://app.kamino.finance/ ...) and the balance is not assigned to the owner's wallet and it is managed within some pool in the protocol/on-chain program/contract. For the latter case, you would need to understand the internals of every (the most known) protocol and verify their transactions that work with "depositing" funds.
With that, I would probably consider researching some services on Solana that do indexing of the blockchain and provide some higher-level API on top of the raw ledger data. I mean e.g., what Helius provides as Enhanced Transaction API (https://docs.helius.dev/solana-apis/enhanced-transactions-api/parsed-transaction-history). I don't think this particular link is exactly what you need to start at but there could be other providers where you can find a list of the history of token transfers as an API call. These providers usually have their explorers. Do your own research but like these

https://docs.solana.fm/reference/solanafm-api-overview-copy
https://public-api.solscan.io/docs/
https://github.com/solana-beach/api
https://docs.helius.dev/solana-apis

If we consider the wallet used the SPL Token and it was transferred to his wallet (to ATA account https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account) then you could potentially work directly with Solana RPC methods https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction
When you download a transaction data and that transaction worked with some token transfers of SPL tokens then the structure you get from RPC call (details on transaction structure at https://medium.com/@asmiller1989/solana-transactions-in-depth-1f7f7fe06ac2) consist fields of preBalance and postBalance. Those fields say what was the amount of tokens before the transaction was processed and after it was processed.
I would try to do like

downloading the list of transactions executed (i.e., list of signatures) in the block
going through the list of signatures one by one and download details
parse preBalance and postBalance fields and verify the difference

Be aware that the RPC endpoints rate limit the number of RPC calls (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)

block data https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getblock

curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0","id":1,
    "method":"getBlock",
    "params": [
      253732587,
      {
        "encoding": "json",
        "maxSupportedTransactionVersion":0,
        "transactionDetails":"signatures",
        "rewards":false
      }
    ]
  }
'


transaction data https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction

curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTransaction",
    "params": [
      "4jBw37MhxrHk1yJjCGSXHnGa3ZTithJqaGPBubE3HqXLJuQW5UPZfARadJkPjo6ubP9zrzsAkhYMCWKNDRXjNPKt",                                 
      {
         "encoding": "json",
         "maxSupportedTransactionVersion": 0
      }
    ]
  }
'


Parse the SPL token balance data and calculate the difference of pre and post-balances. A lot of transactions in the block have no preBalance/postBalance data as they were not processing any token transfers (like 4/5 of transactions on the network could be vote transactions that do no balance related work)

...
"preTokenBalances": [
  {
    "accountIndex": 1,
    "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
    "owner": "CmwPTro4ogHPhuG9Dozx1X7KiATNudF1rkem3BQmuPn7",
    "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
    "uiTokenAmount": {
      "amount": "10795077223",
      "decimals": 9,
      "uiAmount": 10.795077223,
      "uiAmountString": "10.795077223"
    }
  },

...
"postTokenBalances": [
  {
    "accountIndex": 1,
    "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
    "owner": "CmwPTro4ogHPhuG9Dozx1X7KiATNudF1rkem3BQmuPn7",
    "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
    "uiTokenAmount": {
      "amount": "10795077223",
      "decimals": 9,
      "uiAmount": 10.795077223,
      "uiAmountString": "10.795077223"
    }
  },
...

